# Simplifying limit help

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

In my calculus class, I have that
$f(t) = 11.14(1.023)^t$, and I am trying to find the instantaneous rate of change at $t=15$. So far the arithmetic I've done has lead me to
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{11.14(1.023)^{15+h} - 11.14(1.023)^{15}}{h}$$
but I can't seem to further simplify this, and thus I can't think of a solution. Is there something I'm overlooking, i.e. an identity or arithmetic simplification? Thanks.

Comment: It's $f'(15)=11.14(1.023)^{15}\ln1.023$

Comment: Check the limit definiton of derivatives.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a derivative. Without the introduction of the natural log, you are not going to get very fat with the limit definition of the derivative

Comment: @imranfat I haven't been introduced to derivatives yet. I think I can use L'Hopitals though, so thanks.

Comment: Don't you need derivatives for L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: @rss123 Now I am curious. How can you be given L'Hopital as a tool without learning about derivatives?

Comment: (You need the notion of derivative to even *state* the theorem...)

Comment: You need to ask your teacher what are the rules allowed for this problem. Otherwise you will be "running around in circles". Either way, there has to be a derivative somewhere in the game, if you allow $ln$ to be part of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

With first principles, we can generate a general rule of $\frac{d}{dx}a^x$:

$$\frac{d}{dx}a^x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^xa^h-a^x}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^x(a^h-1)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to0}a^x\times\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$$
$$=a^x\times\ln(a)$$

You may be wondering how we get from $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}$ to $\ln(a)$. This site: https://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/calculus/limit-of-ax-1x.html explains it very well. Using this, we can apply it to your question so that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}11.14(1.023)^t=11.14\frac{d}{dx}(1.023)^t=11.14\times1.023^t\times\ln(1.023)$$

Substitute $t=15$ to get the expression $11.14\times1.023^{15}\times\ln(1.023)\approx0.35628731…$